# Enhance app performance with more than 80 views on a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an android application, which has a particular screen (layout) with over (120+ views), which generates the warning:

```
   "main.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance"
```

I have lots of `TextViews`, `EditTexts`, groups of `RadioButtons` organized on 26 `TableRows`.

Is there anything I can do to enhance application performance and remove warning?

source:
[main.xml_capture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/capturenbk.jpg/)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_but_val"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_colored"
            android:text="@string/but_valid"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_but_up"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_colored"
            android:onClick="goToTop"
            android:text="@string/but_ret_up"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/id_but_back"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_colored"
            android:text="@string/but_ret_back"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_84_obstacles_acces" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_oui" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_non" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_85_limit_tonnage" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:ems="@string/editTextEms"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_86_derog" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_87_limit_hauteur" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditText03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:ems="@string/editTextEms"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_88_limit_largeur" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditText04"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:ems="@string/editTextEms"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow06"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_89_trav_jour" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup06"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_oui" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_non" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow07"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_90_acces_intemperies" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup07"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_oui" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_non" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow08"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView08"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/ecran3_91_acces_de_client" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup08"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_oui" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/RadioButton16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_value_non" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/TableRow09"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView09"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                        android:text="@string/ecran3_92_contraintes_reservoir" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                        android:ems="@string/editTextEms"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/TableRow10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/row_margin_top" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/label_width"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                        android:text="@string/ecran3_93_dalle_pret" />

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_left_margin"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/RadioButton19"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/radio_value_oui" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/RadioButton20"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/radio_value_non" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </TableRow>
<!-- TableRow10 to TableRow26 -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try some sort of pagination and split up the form into multiple activites.

Comment: I must have all my form elements inside a scrollable container, so pagination will not work in may case. But thx for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your full layout I would say to replace that `TableLayout` with a `ListView`.
I'm guessing that you have a number of `Views` for each row, if you switch to a `ListView` you'll avoid the need to load the entire layout in memory, instead you'll load only the visible rows on the screen of the `ListView` + any views you have besides that.

With the above approach, you'll be able to remove a substantial number of rows from the current layout.

**EDIT :**

Based on your added layout, some advices:

- `TableRow` can be used as a normal view in a layout but its main purpose it to be a child of a `TableLayout`.
- If you don't want your `Buttons` from `tableRow00` to have equal width then you can make a small improvement and instead of your current layout, replace `LinearLayout00` with a `RelativeLayout`, remove the `tableRow00` and then place the `Buttons` and the `ScrollView` using the rules of `RelativeLayout`.
- Replace `LinearLayout01` with a `TableLayout`.
- I don't know why you added the `LinearLayout02`(I'm guessing all of your rows are the same?!) but you should remove it and directly append `TableRow09` - `TableRow26` to `LinearLayout01`.
- The rest of my answer remains.

Comment: I used LinearLayout02 to dynamically make it visible (or gone) when some conditions regarding input values are met (or not). Thanks for your help!